# Generating rsa key pairs then using copy.deepcopy() on the object generates pickling error !! Any help please?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa, pickle, pycryptodome

Here, I generate a key pair for the transaction then I deepcopy it later, which generates the pickling error:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import random
import sys
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
import copy 

class Transaction():
    def __init__(self,
     id=0,requester=0,requesterPK =0, pubkey=0, privkey=0,data=0):
        self.id = id               #the uinque id or the hash of the transaction   
        self.requester = requester     
        self.requesterPK = requesterPK #Requester primary key
        self.pubkey = pubkey
        self.privkey = privkey
        self.data = data
        self.verified=False
    def create_transactions():# Tx sender changes as the Tx propagates while Tx requester stays same        
        Tn = 5
        simTime = 5
        Psize= int(Tn * simTime) # Tx rate times simTime
        for i in range(Psize):
            # assign values for transactions' attributes. You can ignore some attributes if not of an interest, and the default values will then be used
            tx= Transaction()
            tx.id= random.randrange(100000000000)
            tx.data = f"{tx.id}file.txt"
            file1 = open(tx.data, "w")
            s= str(tx.id)
            file1.write(s)
            tx.requesterPK = RSA.generate(1024)
            tx.privkey = f"{tx.id}Privkey.out"
            f = open(tx.privkey,"wb")
            f.write(tx.requesterPK.exportKey('PEM'))
            f.close()
            tx.requesterPubkey = tx.requesterPK.publickey()
            tx.pubkey = f"{tx.id}Pubkey.out"
            f = open(tx.pubkey, "wb")
            f.write(tx.requesterPubkey.exportKey('OpenSSH'))
            f.close()
            tx.transaction_prop()
    def transaction_prop(self):
        t= copy.deepcopy(self)
Transaction.create_transactions()
```

the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trial2.py", line 47, in <module>
    Transaction.create_transactions()       
  File "trial2.py", line 41, in create_transactions
    tx.transaction_prop()
  File "trial2.py", line 44, in transaction_prop
    t= copy.deepcopy(self)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 270, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 230, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 161, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
  File "/Users/riham/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 210, in __getstate__
    raise PicklingError
_pickle.PicklingError
```